# Monitor on all indexes

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, monitoring

I'm using Oracle 11g.

A lot of times I need to check in

> stats$

tables and snapshots tables if an index has used or no.

My question is - are there any disadvantages or problems to use

> MONITORING USAGE

for all of my indexes? Just put them all inside.

Maybe build a procedure that perform it on every new index?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index monitoring has serious issues pre-12.2:

1)  A boolean flag generally isn't enough information to make a reasonable determination on whether to keep an index or not.  Was that index used 1 time because a developer forced an index using a hint or was the index called hundreds of times?

2)  The check happens at parse phase, not execute phase.  (See the previous point why this is an issue).

3)  There is a performance impact.  While that performance impact is small, especially if you are only turning it on for a single index, that impact will be more significant if you try turning it on for all indexes, system wide.

Index Monitoring is designed to be turned on for a single index (or small group of indexes), wait some reasonable time, then turn it off and check the stats.  It isn't meant to just be on all the time.

In 12.2, Index Monitoring was completely overhauled so that it is on by default for all indexes (I'm pretty sure you can't even turn it off).  Oracle has largely solved most of the issues with index monitoring in previous Oracle versions:  the performance impact is insignificant, more meaningful stats (an actual count of number of times used), and the stats are updated on execute phase, not parse phase.

Tim Hall has a good write up on Index Monitoring [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/index-monitoring).  Connor McDonald has an excellent YouTube video on why Index Monitoring had issues pre-12.2, and what Oracle has done to address these issues [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozAfgU7K5RI) (start watching from 19:15 - 27:05).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! My main goal is for identify unused-at-all indexes, so 1 and 2 are not an issue for me. The performance is the thing I realy want to know. Thanks!

Comment: @user2671057 Happy to help.  It was a good question, and I think most Oracle DBA's have been there since an ideal system will have just enough indexes that it needs, but no more than that.  Therefore, i'm very excited about the 12.2 index monitoring revamp.